# replace number before file extension

Tags: jquery, regex

I would like to replace the number that appears directly before the file extension. My example will replace all numbers unfortunately. Is there a way of doing this without splitting the string at the `/`and then splitting it again at the `.`.

```
// var txt = 'myImage123.gif'; // works ok
// var txt = 'folder1/folder2/123/myImage123.gif'; // replaces numbers out of scope
var txt = 'folder1/folder2/123/my123Image123.gif'; // replaces numbers out of scope
txt = txt.replace(/\d+/,'999');

$('h3').text(txt);
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/6mBeQ/244/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
txt = txt.replace(/\d+(?=\.gif$)/m,'999');
```

This should match one or more digit chars which exists just before to the last `.gif` and then it replace those matched chars with `999`

or

```
txt = txt.replace(/\d+(?=\.\w+$)/m,'999');
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Not sure who down voted it. I'll accept when allowed.

Comment: This fails if used on a css background url - any reason for this? demo http://jsfiddle.net/6mBeQ/247/

Comment: Thanks - what does `\b` do and why didn't your original example work?

Comment: `\b` matches between a word char or non-word char. First regex fails because I have added `$` which matches end of the line. BUt in your second ex, there are more chars following the comma

Answer (score 0):

Another method without using `lookaround` or `capturing groups` would be direct replacement.

**Regex:** `\d+\.gif`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with your number ( e.g 999) + `.gif`. It would be `999.gif`.

**Code:** `txt = txt.replace(/\d+\.gif/,'999.gif');`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB8tQ6/1)**

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mBeQ/250/)**